# Using json_decod() for json objects whose attributes have long string length. I cannot get it to work

Tags: json

When I have using `json_decode(someJsonObject)` I can generate an array and read off the attributes.  However, when one of these attributes contain text of around 821 characters, i cannot generate an array. And the json_decode appears not to recognise an object even though I have validated the json representation (via http://jsonlint.com/). Please can some one help?

My json object that I cannot decode:

```
[{"abstractText":"Ebola viruses and Marburg viruses include some of the most virulent and    fatal pathogens known to humans. These viruses cause severe haemorrhagic fevers, with case fatality rates in the range 25-90%. The diagnosis of filovirus using formalin-fixed tissues from fatal cases poses a significant challenge. The most characteristic histopathological findings are seen in the liver; however, the findings overlap with many other viral and non-viral haemorrhagic diseases. The need to distinguish filovirus infections from other haemorrhagic fevers, particularly in areas with multiple endemic viral haemorrhagic agents, is of paramount importance. In this review we discuss the current state of knowledge of filovirus infections and their pathogenesis, including histopathological findings, epidemiology, modes of transmission and filovirus entry and spread within host organisms. The pathogenesis of filovirus infections is complex and involves activation of the mononuclear phagocytic system, with release of pro-inflammatory cytokines, chemokines and growth factors, endothelial dysfunction, alterations of the innate and adaptive immune systems, direct organ and endothelial damage from unrestricted viral replication late in infection, and coagulopathy. Although our understanding of the pathogenesis of filovirus infections has rapidly increased in the past few years, many questions remain unanswered. Copyright © 2014 Pathological Society of Great Britain and Ireland. Published by John Wiley \u0026 Sons, Ltd.","authorString":"Martines RB, Ng DL, Greer PW, Rollin PE, Zaki SR.","issue":"2","journalTitle":"J. Pathol.","pageInfo":"153-174","pmid":"25297522","pubYear":"2015","title":"Tissue and cellular tropism, pathology and pathogenesis of Ebola and Marburg viruses.","volume":"235"},{"abstractText":"Good medical ethics needs to look more to the resources of public health ethics and use more societal, population or community values and perspectives, rather than defaulting to the individualistic values that currently dominate discussion. In this paper I argue that we can use the recent response to Ebola as an example of a major failure of the global community in three ways. First, the focus has been on the treatment of individuals rather than seeing that the priority ought to be public health measures. Second, the advisory committee on experimental interventions set up by the WHO has focused on ethical issues related to individuals and their guidance has been unclear. Third, the Ebola issue can be seen as a symptom of a massive failure of the global community to take sufficient notice of global injustice.","authorString":"Dawson AJ.","issue":"1","journalTitle":"J Med Ethics","pageInfo":"107-110","pmid":"25516949","pubYear":"2015","title":"Ebola: what it tells us about medical ethics.","volume":"41"}]
```

Comment: [works for me](http://codepad.org/FM9onuvx)

Comment: oh ok..thanks..this is very strange..been trying to get this work for the past 2 days.

Comment: please could you show me the code you used?  Even when I "echo count(json_decode(someJsonObject)) " I am getting a count of 0.

Comment: http://codepad.org/FM9onuvx

Comment: thanks for the post Peter. I copied and paste your code but I just get a blank. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, i get a  "NULL"  to be exact. and the count(json_decode($json)) give me "0".

Comment: what PHP version do you use? also what text editor do you use? windows notepad is not good in most cases.

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.15, Notepad++.

Comment: can you please post source to codepad.org and paste it here?

Comment: I've posted the full code here. it is the same problem which i have been trying to unsuccussfuly diagnose. [](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717639/problems-converting-a-utf-8-encoded-text-to-a-json-object-json-object-not-utf-8)

Comment: json from that link is not valid because there is line break after `ssue":"2","journalTitle":"J. `